# Child view is not inflating in the Android Cardboard

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I am trying to inflate the custom view inside cardboard overlay view and only the parent view is inflating i.e., Relative Layout.

Here is the code of CardboardOverlayView :

```
public class CardboardOverlayView extends LinearLayout {

    private final CardboardOverlayEyeView leftView;
    private final CardboardOverlayEyeView rightView;

    public CardboardOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

        leftView = new CardboardOverlayEyeView(context, attrs);
        leftView.setLayoutParams(params);
        addView(leftView);

        rightView = new CardboardOverlayEyeView(context, attrs);
        rightView.setLayoutParams(params);
        addView(rightView);

        setDepthOffset(0.016f);
        setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    private void setDepthOffset(float offset) {
        leftView.setOffset(offset);
        rightView.setOffset(-offset);
    }

    private class CardboardOverlayEyeView extends ViewGroup {

        private float offset;
        private ListView listView;
        private View view;
        private String[] item = new String[]{"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"};

        public CardboardOverlayEyeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

            super(context, attrs);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null, true);

            this.listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item Clicked: " + adapter.getItemId(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            this.addView(view);
        }

        public void setOffset(float offset) {
            this.offset = offset;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {

            final int width = right - left;
            final int height = bottom - top;
            final float imageSize = 0.1f;
            final float verticalImageOffset = -0.07f;
            final float verticalTextPos = 0.52f;
            float adjustedOffset = offset;

            float imageMargin = (1.0f - imageSize) / 2.0f;
            float leftMargin = (int) (width * (imageMargin + adjustedOffset));
            float topMargin = (int) (height * (imageMargin + verticalImageOffset));

            leftMargin = adjustedOffset * width;
            topMargin = height * verticalTextPos;

            view.layout((int) 100, (int) 100, (int) (width - 100), (height - 100));
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the custom layout which I am trying to inflate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1bd5b9">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The screenshot is attached:

[Cardboard Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alu45.png)

Comment: The issue is resolved, instead of extending the RelativeLayout I was extending the ViewGroup in CardboardOverlayEyeView method.

Comment: hey about focus on items ? are u have problem when on leftview item focused but on rightview item not focused?